# Change default contact picture for iphone

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, contacts, photos, graphics

This is most likely a jailbreak-related question...

Is there a known application to mass/bulk change the default picture for contacts without a picture?

Ie: I just added John Doe and I have no picture for him, so he has a silhouette when you look at his contact information.

How can I change all contacts with that same silhouette to, say, a deer?

Comment: The quickest solution would be to whip up a quick Winterboard theme.

Answer (score 1):

for themes there is PBcontact Photo, which makes contact photos a playboy icon

so it can be done, but there is no app that can help you customize this easily without building your own theme to make default contact photo set to what you want